# JavaScript - Parsing a dynamic json

Tags: javascript, json

I'm working on a web-app in Node.JS.

In order **to parse a dynamic JSON** variable I have followed [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549078/how-to-parse-and-output-json-object-with-dynamic-values)

However I'm new to JSON and I have a particular JSON response coming from a Server.
Here's a piece of JSON response

```
[{"results":[{"name":"AIENR","tags":{"ch":["922"],"mq":["EMPTY","REAL"],"vs":
["VALID"]},"values":[[1352934000000,145258],[1352934900000,145258],
[1352935800000,145259],[....]
```

**The problem:**
I want to access to fields inside `"values"`, so in my html page I've done this:

```
<p>Values: </p>  
<%for (var nodeIndex in queries[0].results[0].values) {%>
        <p><%= queries[0].results[0].values[nodeIndex] %></p>
    <%}%>
```

and the output (that is correct) is:

```
Values:

1352934000000,145258

1352934900000,145258

1352935800000,145259

1352936700000,145259

... , ...
```

Anyway, due to fact that the first value is a timestamp and the second value is a particular measure, **I want to store them separately** and maybe in the next days use those values to make a chart.

**So my question is:** How can I split those two values?

Best Wishes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: `.values[nodeIndex]` is an array. You can access the first element with `.values[nodeIndex][0]` and second one with `.values[nodeIndex][1]`.

Comment: Thanks! It solved! it was really simple. I was stuck on the value[i].anotherValue[0] approach, forgetting that's was an array. Hope will be useful to someone else :)

Comment: I made it an answer so that you can mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.values[nodeIndex]` is an array. You can access the first element with `.values[nodeIndex][0]` and second one with `.values[nodeIndex][1]`.